# How do I Authenticate user before cucumber test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to wrap my head around BDD using Cucumber (for feature tests) and RSpec (for Unit Tests).

I am having trouble writing my first test for Cucumber. I need to authenticate first, but don't know how.

```
Given(/^A logged in user$/) do
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "Email Address", :with => "sebhastien@gibosse.com"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "123456"
    click_button "Log In"
end

When(/^I go to the teams page$/) do
    visit teams_path
end

Then(/^I should see a list of my teams$/) do
    expect(page).to have_content("Teams#index")
end
```

Feature:

```
Feature: Hello Cucumber
    As a user
    I want to see a list of teams on the Teams page
    So that I can manage them

    Background: User is Authenticated
        Given A logged in user

    Scenario: User sees teams
        When I go to the teams page
        Then I should see a list of my teams
```

I expect the test to pass now. But it seems that it is getting the "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing" on the sign-in page.

Comment: Not clear with the exact scenario, but check `background` in cucumber where you can authenticate the user. Alternatively you can use `before` hook.

Comment: @supputuri I added the feature file. I am getting the same issue when using background

Comment: Might this help https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Cucumber

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```rb
Given (/^I am not authenticated$/) do
    visit('/users/sign_out') # ensure that at least
end

Given (/^I am a new, authenticated user$/) do
    email = 'testing@man.net'
    password = 'secretpass'
    User.new(:email => email, :password => password, :password_confirmation => password).save!

    visit '/users/sign_in'
    fill_in "user_email", :with => email
    fill_in "user_password", :with => password
    click_button "Log In"

end

When(/^I go to the teams page$/) do
    visit teams_path
end

Then(/^I should see a list of my teams$/) do
    expect(page).to have_content("Teams#index")
end
```

Feature:

```
Feature: Hello Cucumber
    As a user
    I want to see a list of teams on the Teams page
    So that I can manage them

    Background: User Authenticates
        Given I am not authenticated
        Given I am a new, authenticated user

    Scenario: User sees teams
        When I go to the teams page
        Then I should see a list of my teams
```